# Why does implementing text have adverse impact on 3D models in Visual Studio XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, monogame, spritebatch

When I tried adding text to my MonoGame program, I encountered a problem. It stopped rendering 3D objects properly, cutting front faces on some, not displaying others altogether.

I've tried ending the batch after drawing the models too, to the same effect

```
public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        string output = "Score";

        spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, output, Vector2.Zero, Color.LightGreen,
            0, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0.5f);

        spriteBatch.End();
        foreach (BasicModel model in models)
        {
            model.Draw(((Game1)Game).GraphicsDevice, ((Game1)Game).mainCamera);
        }
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Why is my text implementation screwing up my 3D models?

Comment: The last parameter in the `DrawString()` method is the depth. `0.5f` means, you render it right in the middle between the nearplane and the farplane. So maybe your rendered text is just intersecting your objects in the scene? Try a value of `0.0f` just for test and check, if the result changes.

Comment: Attempted. no success. Thx for the suggestion, i overlooked that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SpriteBatch.Begin() changes some grapic pipeline render states in a way that is best for 2d rendering but not for 3d rendering.

So after rendering your 2d, you need to reset those states for the 3d rendering.

```
GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
```

Now your 3d will draw fine. [See this link for more info.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/06/18/spritebatch-and-renderstates-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx)

Add those 2 lines between your `spriteBatch.End()` and your `foreach()`